# Как переформатировать INSERT JOIN запрос с MySql на PostgreSQL

Tags: mysql, postgresql

В общем, мигрирую своего телеграм бота с mysql на postgresql и появилась необходимость переформатировать данный запрос:

```
UPDATE t_users t1 JOIN t_users t2 ON t2.chatId = %d SET (t1.subscribe) = (t2.team) WHERE t1.chatId = %d;
```

Непонятно, куда девать ON?

Comment: не понятно что это запрос делал. потому что в ON таблицы join никак не связаны между собой, следовательно запрос порождал декартово произведение всех строк и каким то случайным образом раскидывал новые значения. Либо у вас структура самой БД такова, что этого не происходило (t_users.chitId уникален). но такие нюансы должны быть указаны в вопросе, что бы можно было сделать запрос который будет делать действительно то, что необходимо. Еще интересно те 2 параметра %d это одинаковое число или разные

Comment: В общем, разобрался, запрос обновлял подписку в поле subscribe из поля  team.

Comment: И да, %d одинаковое число

Comment: тогда не ясно что давал join. по факту в t1 были те же записи, что и в t2, т.е. данные брались из той же самой записи, которая обновлялась. Но тогда `update t_users set subscribe = team where chatId = 1` должно быть более чем достаточно

Comment: Хмм... Я писал этот запрос для mysql аж в сентябре и помню, что тогда возникли определенные трудности, точно уж не помню какие...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Разобрался:

```
UPDATE t_users t1 SET subscribe = t2.team FROM t_users t2  WHERE t1.chatId = 1 AND t2.chatId = 1;
```